# error stating "min() arg is an empty sequence"

Tags: python, list

i dont understand the error because I've also passed the value in min fuction. I dont know wht's going on.

**error:  ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence**

here is the code:

```
def smallest_even(li):
even = []
for item in li:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        even.append(item)
    return min(even)


print(smallest_even([3, 4, 2, 1, 34, 65, 82]))
```

Comment: Move your `return` statement to the left by 4 spaces. You don't want it to run until your `for` loop is done.

Comment: Thank you it worked! but i still dont know wht was causing the error.

Comment: Also, you'll get that error in the case that `li` doesn't have any even numbers.  You may want to handle that in some way.  An option would be something like `min(even, default=float('-inf'))`.  Negative infinity is a pretty good default for `min`, but it isn't an integer and certainly not even so you may want some other handling.  Possibly an error is actually the desired behavior.  It all depends on your use case.

Comment: You were getting the error because in the first time through the loop `item = 3` and so `even` remained `[]`.  Then you called `min` on an empty list and Python threw an error because it doesn't know what to return in this case.

Comment: thank you so much for you help Kyle, i'm sorry i just started python.

Comment: You don't have to pick a default. If the caller is going to be careless about passing a list with no applicable minimum value, *they* can provide a default. `def smallest_even(li, default=None): ...; return min(even, default=default)`. A "default default" of `None` is reasonable; you can document it as such and let the caller pick another if they care.

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation

```
def smallest_even(li):
    even = []
    for item in li:
        if item % 2 == 0:
            even.append(item)
    if even:
        return min(even)
    else:
        return None  # There is no even number in the input list


print(smallest_even([3, 4, 2, 1, 34, 65, 82]))
```

Comment: You'll still get the error if there are no even numbers in the input.